# Reinstalled MetaMask, account lost?

Tags: ether, wallets, metamask, addresses, accounts

I had 3 accounts under my MetaMask Chrome extension. One of them had some small deposit. I have reinstalled the extension and used seed phrase to get access again. However, I can see only one account (with zero funds).

Does it mean I lost access forever? I've read that a seed phrase gets access to a whole list of addresses. I still know the public key of the needed lost account. Is it possible to recover, still?

Comment: What network are you connected to in Metamask?

Comment: Main ethereum network

Comment: I delet an Accoubt because it was stokes. Bet i need to recover. O do t have the priva-te key bit i have the seed phrase

Comment: 0xdb3530de8bfd6839032d3b74a0bee553952a4c36
This is my metamask address. How can I retrieve it. Please is there anyone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get your accounts back by clicking "Create Account" (once per each account).

The accounts are there, however they are not shown until you add them.

If the accounts that show up do not match what you are expecting, then you are using an incorrect seed.

Comment: I'm sure seed is correct. I have added 5 accounts but the one I need is still not there. This looks like a lottery - is there any other ways to reach my account? May be use another wallet?

Comment: Thanks all, the problem was trivial - the seed phrase was correct but it was the wrong one. :/ After I used the right one, my "lost" account was the first one.

Comment: Does this mean that in order to consider myself backed up I most know not only my seed phrase but also the correct spelling of all my accounts?

Answer (score 1):

No your account is safe or, better, if you still have the private key of the account you are interested in, your money and your account are safe. You are definitively able to recover them using some other wallet. I use CIPHER on iOS and it is ok. On the other side, simply add a new account in metamask giving the private key when asked for it. Nothing more.

**after the comment**

Sorry, I did not realize that you do not have the private key. I can suggest you to do the following: install Ganache windows or Mac version (google “Truffle Ganache”).Put in its account menu the seed phrase you have. This will create 10 address for you from the phrase. The first should coincide with the first created by metamask.

Add one by one those address in metamask: in Ganache you will have the private key of each address available.

If this way you do not succeed and you do not have a private key for the relevant address, it is lost forever.

Comment: That's the problem. I do not have private key for that one (exported others but forgot this one) :/

Comment: I'll try to recover but even more I'd like to understand how it works - looks like relation from phrase to addresses list is not quite deterministic? I mean the phrase to first address is deterministic but what's with others addresses? Anywhere I can read about it?

Comment: Ok, solved the issue (see above). Looks like "Create account" is consistent and picks addresses always in the same sequence.

Comment: Yes, it is simply a question of nonce. It is deterministic.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
I solved it by creating a new Address with the same name as the one that was lost.