# Why can't I reach my account, after I imported my metamask account using my mnemonic seed phrases?

Tags: web3js, metamask, recovery, mnemonic

I have used metamask on my old computer, where I had multiple accounts in it. When I moved to my new computer, I used the mnemonic phrase to import my existing wallet. The accounts that are now created out of the same seed phrases have different keys.

I know I could export the private keys on my old computer, and import the exact same account into the new metamask using the private key too, but I still do not understand why it is not the same automatically?

If I would have gotten my computer stolen, and I would have thought backing up only the seed phrases is enough, would I have lost all my balances?

Comment: well this should not happen, thus you might are missing something (like that you have your mnemonic wrong)

Comment: The mnemonic seed phrases are right, because I have access to both computers and I could copy and paste the words. I have also seen this problem with others online, and I do not understand how it happens.

Comment: @curiousTrader Does the answers from question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78591/reinstalled-metamask-account-lost work for you?